# NUnit3 TestCaseData: SetName prevents test execution

Tags: c#

I have very simple code. Such way it works.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> MyTestData()        
    {
        TestCaseData tcd = new TestCaseData(2, 3);
        //tcd.SetName("first");
        //tcd.TestName = "first";
        yield return tcd;
        //yield return new TestCaseData(1, 2).SetName("second");
    }

    [TestCaseSource("MyTestData")]
    public static void Addition(int i, int j)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sum = {i+j}");
    }
```

If I uncomment any of commented lines VS2017 cannot start this test. It tries, shows wait icon and... nothing. No errors, no messages. Could you please help me what can be wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I'm using NUnit from nuget, package version is 3.11

Comment: May be it is a limitation of VS2017... I tried your code in VS2015 and had no problems: test cases are executed and test session shows "first" and "second" labels. CAUTION: I used Resharper test runner to launch tests...

Comment: >I'm using NUnit from nuget, package version is 3.11
>
me too

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm getting the same issue with NUnit 3.11 in VS2017 (v15.9.11).

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately, I don't remember the root cause. Here is my working test project.  
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6V29/3Fm7fsfJ3